# Дизассемблирование java игры для телефона

Tags: java

Есть ли программа для преобразования jar в начальный код midletpascal?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего нету, потому что midletpascal не популярный продукт. Но вы можете получить жава код, где это возможно, обычным декомпилером.

ЗЫ: а вы уверены что игра написана на паскале?

Answer (score -3):

Совет - откройте .jar файлик архиватором каким нибудь.
Например WinRar'ом.
А дальше уже из Jav'ы что нибудь пробуйте.